# Unexpected output in string format with instance variables

Tags: ruby

I am writing a console application and I want to display a prompt with the command number (i.e a variable that is increased every time the user presses enter).

Expected output:

```
[0] app_name >
1
[1] app_name >
2
[2] app_name >
```

Here is the code:

```
class Prompt
  attr_accessor :format, :string, :prompt, :index
  def initialize
    init_vars
    @format = "[%s] %s > "
    @string = [@index, "app_name"]
    @prompt = @format % @string
  end
  def init_vars
    @index = 0
  end
  def update_prompt
    @index += 1
    @prompt = @format % @string
  end
end

require 'readline'

prompt = Prompt.new
while last = Readline.readline(prompt.prompt)
  prompt.update_prompt
  puts prompt.index
end
```

Output:

```
[0] app_name >
1
[0] app_name >
2
[0] app_name >
```

When I change this line:

```
@prompt = @format % @string
```

to:

```
@prompt = @format % [@index, "app_name"]
```

I plan to use this for an internal framework, and would like the user to specify the `@format` and the `@string` and produce the prompt. I believe that changing the line as above would not work.

May someone explain what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Here is the working code:

```
class Prompt

  attr_accessor :format, :string, :prompt, :index

  def initialize
    @index = -1
    @format = "[%d] %s > "
    update_prompt
  end

  def update_prompt
    @index += 1
    @string = @index, "app_name"
    @prompt = @format % @string
  end

end

require 'readline'

prompt = Prompt.new
while last = Readline.readline(prompt.prompt)
  prompt.update_prompt
  #de puts prompt.index
end
```

#### Output is as expected:

```
[0] app_name > 
[1] app_name > 
[2] app_name > 
[3] app_name > 
[4] app_name > 
[5] app_name > 
[6] app_name >
```

---

The `@string` was being frozen at `@index == 0` so it needed to be updated, like `@index` was. I too thought `@index` would update, and that only a reference was being stored in `@string`, but the value was being stored... not a reference that could be updated. I'm curious as to why, but I've fixed the code regardless.

---

Knowing what we know about how `@string` will be handled...

#### Here is an even smaller version:

```
class Prompt

  attr_accessor :format, :string, :prompt, :index

  def initialize
    @index = -1
    @format = "[%d] %s > "
    update_prompt
  end

  def update_prompt
    @prompt = @format % [ @index += 1, "app_name" ]
  end

end
```

Comment: so, from the looks of it, the problem is that I am using a variable in an array, and the the value in the array does not change.  You can test this out by doing something like this `a = 1 ; b = [a]  ; a += 1 ; puts b` b should show `1` instead of `2`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the issue is that the `@index` is updated, but the `@string` is not. So if I add `@string = [@index, "app_name"]` right after the index increment in the `update_prompt` method, it should work.